Redirect URL with fragments in it
I have an third party iFrame, that generates links like this:
https://www.example.com/en/media/#/pressreleases/article-title
I'm outfacing the iFrame with a custom API integration. Everything is working fine, but I need to create redirects for the old URL's since there's many post on SoME with the old URL's
Site is a WordPress site, and I use Yoast SEO redirect.
However, my redirects doesn't trigger, and I think it's because of the fragment #.
Any tricks I can do in my function.php or something?
I'm also using Cloudflare and WpEngine if there's any option I can utilise there.
Tried Yoast Redirect, with no luck.

I don’t know about your specific problem, but I can tell you that the fragment portion of a URL is never sent to the server, so there’s nothing in PHP that can (directly) affect that portion, it must be done client-side

You would need to create something here, that loads a basic HTML document, when https://www.example.com/en/media/ gets requested. JavaScript in that document can then access the URI fragment (location.hash), and either redirect directly (if you can determine the correct target URL in JS, based on the fragement value), or it could send that value to the server first, if you can only determine the correct redirection target there.

Yeah, I ended up with a Javascript solution, even though it's not ideal. But it is what it is.
